# Вывести не полный список товаров jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Мне нужно вывести не полный список товаров на странице. То есть их, например, в сумме 40, и я хочу, чтобы первоначально показывалось 10, и нажимая на 1.2.3..20 выводились остальные. Как вариант была мысль в начале посылать массив с первыми 10 товарами, и в зависимости от нажатия кидать пересылать массив с товарами, индекс которых 20-29, 30-39 и так далее. Выглядит как велосипед, поэтому прошу помощи.Буду благодарен за ссылки на примеры.

[image: Вот так]

Comment: Можно выгрузить все товары. в цикле их записать в html код. первые 10 оставить видимыми, а остальные скрыть. Когда проходит одна десятка считать страницу. И к элементу на странице присваивать страницу в виде атрибута `data-page="1"`. А потом при смене страницы на JS отображать элементы которые подходят по `data-page` атрибуту.

При этом не будет over 100 запросов и переходов.

Comment: В массиве товары откуда появляются? Из БД?